# html tags added in the java exception message not getting reflected

Tags: java

I am throwing an exception in one of my method and while throwing I need some part of the message to be in separate line. When i tried adding `<br>` to the message, the tag is not getting reflected and it is getting displayed as text. I have googled and tried adding some ascii keys to the message but none of them have worked.

I am tagging only java as this is is related to general topic

```
throw new Exception("Please contact administrator. Technical information: Ip Address: 127.36.42.23, session id:kfgjdfkgjdflkjgfdgjgh ");
```

Technical information has to come in second line.

Comment: Can you provide your code, please?

Comment: Please show the code you are using, we cant help without it :)

Comment: Use the System.lineSeparator() value to generate a break line. Don't perform it  only visually in your editor.

Comment: Don't you need to at least add <br /> to start a separate line?

Comment: @steve Smith. As mentioned tried adding it. <br> tag is getting displayed

Comment: @Mistalis added the code that i tried

Comment: @Venkatesswara Rao Devarapalem It wasn't escaped in your question so no-one could see it.  I've edited it now.

Comment: What is displaying the error message?  A browser?

Answer (score 0):

To separate line, concat a \n (newline) such like this

```
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("My error is "+e.getMessage+"\n while my cause is: "+e.getCause);
}
```

Comment: It's works. Try throw new Exception("Please contact administrator.\n Technical information:\nIp Address: 127.36.42.23,\nsession id:kfgjdfkgjdflkjgfdgjgh "); . If does not work, probably you have a strange  wrapper around...